# Multiply a float and a vector? So val scale : float -> float*float -> float*float?

Tags: f#

How do I make a function scale(), that multiplies a float and a vector. It has to use this library shown here? I think it's called library, sorry if that is wrong.

```
/// Multiplication of a float and a vector
val scale : float -> float * float -> float * float
```

Spent 4 hours trying to figure it out.

My assignment (Data sciences 3rd week) is, I have a signature-file containing a 2D vector library and I need to make functions out of it using that library.

```
/// A 2D vector library

/// Vectors are represented as pairs of floats module vec2d

/// The length of a vector
val len : float * float -> float
/// The angle of a vector
val ang : float * float -> float
/// Multiplication of a float and a vector
val scale : float -> float * float -> float * float
/// Addition of two vectors
val add : float * float -> float * float -> float * float
/// Dot product of two vectors
val dot : float * float -> float * float -> float
```

Currently I have:

```
// LENGTH OF A VECTOR
// val len : float * float -> float
let len (x: float, y: float) =
    sqrt(x**2.0 + y**2.0)

// ANGLE OF A VECTOR
// val ang : float * float -> float
let ang (x: float, y: float) =
    Math.Atan2(y, x)

// MULTIPLICATION OF A FLOAT AND A VECTOR
// val scale : float -> float * float -> float * float
let scale () =
    None

/// ADDITION OF TWO VECTORS
// add : float * float -> float * float -> float * float 
let add (xy1: float, xy2: float) =
    None 

/// DOT PRODUCT OF TWO VECTORS
// dot : float * float -> float * float -> float
let dot (xy1: float, xy2: float) =
    None
```

[image]

Any kind of help/hint would be really helpful! I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
let scale n (x: float, y: float) =
    n*x, n*y
```

This multiplies each of the values in the vector tuple (x,y) with the float n.